# How to access current Redux state with Reselect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I want to return a value based on the last value from the same selector. e.g.

```
const myReselect = createSelector(
  [otherSelector],
  (otherValue) => {
    // how to access current state?
    return state.myReselect + 1
  }
)

const globalState = state => ({
  myReselect: myReselect(state)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine several selectors to create a more complex selection.

For example, you have `selectorA`, that returns some data, then you want to combine data from `selectorA` and some other data from `state.dataB`.

Create an extra `selectorB` and make a final combined version:

```
// this is reusable selector
import selectorA from './selectorA';

// this is our local selector 
const selectorB = state => state.dataB;

const finalSelector = createSelector(
   selectorA,
   selectorB,
   (a, b) => {
     return a + b;
   }
);

// pubish our resulting selector
export default finalSelector;
```

`finalSelector` will be updated only when some of the dependent selectors was changed

Comment: Isn't this a bad practice as the whole point behind createSelector is that it is only rerun when some of it's input changes thus preventing expensive logic from running multiple times. This will make it so that myReselect runs any time any part of the state changes even parts I don't care about.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I also have learned something for the last almost a year. See my updated answer.